# I keep getting this error about my variable not being defined

Tags: laravel

I am getting this error saying "Undefined variable: stq" and the variable is there. I looked to see if I missed something but I don't see what I'm missing. What is the problem?

Here is my code

```
$stq=str_replace(", ", " ,", $userinputt);

   $pro=User::Where('tags','Like','%'. $str .'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strrr,$strr,$strrrr) {
    $query->Where('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strr .'%')->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrr .'%')->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrrr .'%')->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $stq .'%');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: With variables like `$strrr`, `$strr`, `$strrrr`, who needs enemies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Lol! The other variable $strr, $strrr, $strrrr there okay. Its just when i added the $stq it told me it was undefined as if the varibles not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the $stq variable in the function like this

```
$stq=str_replace(", ", " ,", $userinputt);

 $pro=User::Where('tags','Like','%'. $str .'%')
->Where(function ($query) use($strrr,$strr,$strrrr,$stq) {

$query->Where('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strr .'%')
->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrr .'%')
->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $strrrr .'%')
->orWhere('cityandstate', 'LIKE', '%'. $stq .'%');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.